# NGINX JSON log format

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We have tried to get the error logs in JSON format as we can do for access logs. But we are getting error there.
Can we not format the error logs we are getting from NGINX server to JSON format as we can do for access logs?

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) the `json` log format is available in nginx

```
log_format logger-json escape=json '{
    "source": "nginx",
    "time": $msec,
    "resp_body_size": $body_bytes_sent,
    "host": "$http_host",
    "address": "$remote_addr",
    "request_length": $request_length,
    "method": "$request_method",
    "uri": "$request_uri",
    "status": $status,
    "user_agent": "$http_user_agent",
    "resp_time": $request_time,
    "upstream_addr": "$upstream_addr"
}';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log logger-json;
```

Answer (score -1):

At the moment is not possible to format the error logs as JSON.